# sweetviz installed but won't run: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'warnings'

Tags: python

Goal: Automated exploratory data visualizations with correlations and linear plots that lets you specify a target, dependent variable.

Trying: Sweetviz, in miniconda environment (using conda install rather than pip)

Numpy version is
numpy 1.24.3 py311hdab7c0b_1
numpy-base 1.24.3 py311hd01c5d8_1

Sweetviz is installed:
[image]

But when I try to use it I get an error:
[image]

I tried downgrading numpy, but it impacts other packages that I need. Please advise: Is there a different package I could use that would work with a target variable? How could I get sweetviz to work if not? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Maintainer of the `sweetviz` here; there were a bunch of incompatibilities that sprung up recently, so we just updated sweetviz to 2.2.1 to support the latest versions of numpy and pandas. That error should be gone now, by updating sweetviz to the latest.

This can be done using `pip install sweetviz --upgrade`. There HAVE been issues sometimes with upgrading, so the upgrade fails you can do a clean install by uninstalling then reinstalling:

```
pip uninstall sweetviz
pip install sweetviz
```